# What exception type should be used in Powershell to catch a XML parse error due to invalid characters?

Tags: powershell, exception, xml-parsing, powershell-2.0

Line 2 in the script below generates -

> "Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type
>   "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "'→', hexadecimal value 0x1A, is an
>   invalid character. Line 39, position 23."
>
> At line:1 char:8
>   + [xml]$x <<<<  = Get-Content 4517.xml
>       + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException"

What exception should be specified on line 4 (of the script) to catch the aforementioned error?

```
try {
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content $file # line 2
}
catch [?] {                       # line 4
    echo "XML parse error!"
    # handle the parse error differently
}
catch {
    echo $error
    # some general error
}
```

Thanks for looking (and answering)

Adrian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to discover yourself the full type name of an Exception, the result here gives System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationMetadataException as given by @Adrian Wright.

```
Clear-Host
try {
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content "c:\Temp\1.cs" # line 2
}
catch {
    # Discovering the full type name of an exception
    Write-Host $_.Exception.gettype().fullName
    Write-Host $_.Exception.message
}
```

Answer (score 3):

System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationMetadataException